# Program to simulate seven segment display in atmel studio

Tags: microcontroller, avr, simulation, atmel

I am using Atmel studio for the programming of atmega64 microcontrollers with a Cerebot board II.

Firstly, is there a program that can simulate a seven segment display device as if I was looking at the device in front of me plugging it into a Cerebot board II?

Secondly, is there a built in function of Atmel studio 6 that can simulate a seven segment for me?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at Atmel Studio I couldn't see any apparent way to add any form of custom debugging plug-ins so I lodged a support request. As well as pre-written ones I also asked about the possibility of writing custom plug-ins and here is the verbatim response I received:

> Unfortunately, we do not have a custom debugging plug- in for the
>   display of I/O registers as of now. For the list of available
>   extensions with Atmel studio 6, please visit the below link:
>
> http://gallery.atmel.com/
>
> Hope this helps. Please get back to us in case of further queries.

While the question of whether it is possible to develop custom extensions that can read the I/O registers doesn't seem to have been addressed with 100% clarity looking through the list of gallery extensions I can't see anything that performs any similar functions.

Comment: Custom plugins would be a great feature for Atmel Studio (or any debugger)